# How to read Serial data with Python from more then one Arduino ADC?

Tags: python, string, arduino, serial-port, export-to-csv

I am begginer in Python. I am trying to write serial port data from Arduino to CSV file in Python.
I want to save data in format: time, sensor1, sensor2 as numbers allowing to open them in Excel in separate columns.
My code allows to obtain CSV as follows:

12:25:57,"294,293"
I cannot remove the quotations.

My Arduino code for serial output:

```
Serial.print(sensorValue_1);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(sensorValue_2);
delay(1000);
```

My Python code:

```
import csv
import serial
import time

ser=serial.Serial("COM15", 9600)
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    ser_bytes = ser.readline().decode().strip()


    t = time.localtime()
    decoded_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', t)
    print(decoded_time, ser_bytes)
    with open("test_file.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",")
        writer.writerow([decoded_time, ser_bytes])
        f.close()
```

I will appreciate the help.

Comment: can you show what output you want?

Comment: Hi,
as an output I would like to get something like this (x, y1, y2):

12:25:56, 363, 351
12:25:57, 294, 293
12:25:58, 279, 276

I want to use it for making graphs in Excel or Matplotlib. 
Miron

Comment: So put that in your question, not buried in comments.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code and add some comments.
try this if this is what you need.

```
import csv
import serial
import time

ser=serial.Serial("COM15", 9600)
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    #use split(',') to seperate ser_byte string to list
    ser_bytes = ser.readline().decode().strip().split(',')

    # using list comprehension to perform conversion to int
    new_ser_bytes = [int(i) for i in ser_bytes]

    #new_ser_bytes[0] is sensorValue_1
    #new_ser_bytes[1] is sensorValue_2
    
    t = time.localtime()
    decoded_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', t)
    #print(decoded_time, ser_bytes)
    with open("test_file.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",")
        #writerow with seperate sensorValue
        writer.writerow([decoded_time, new_ser_bytes[0], new_ser_bytes[1]])
        f.close()
```